# How to call this function in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-c and learning it but right I got stuck at understanding below code snippet. 
I would really appreciate if someone knows how to call this function and how to create handle object and pass it to this method.

```
(void)downloadCACertificateWithValidatorDelegate:(id<MscHTTPSValidatorDelegate>)validatorDelegate completionHandler:(MscSCEPDownloadCACertificateCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
```

Comment: It depends where that method is defined and where it's being called from.  If it's within the same class then it's `[self downloadCACertificateWithValidatorDelegate:delegate completionHandler:^(whatever) { something}];`

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe, How to create MscHTTPSValidatorDelegate delegate?

Comment: You need to make a class compliant to that protocol (not sure how, I've never seen it before), but if you have a class compliant to that protocol, you cast it using (id<McsHTTPSValidatorDelegate>)object

Comment: In Objective-C you don't have to cast it. It being the object.